# How do I add descriptive text to form link .gif?

Tags: css, forms, hyperlink

I want to make the descriptive text around a form link also open the form. I want to make it so you can click on "Some Text Here" (below) and open the form on somesomite.com just as if you clicked on the image below this text (somebut.gif, below)

```
<DIV style="position: absolute; top:10px; right:10px; width:70px; height:25px">
<font color="white"><b>Some Text Here<b></font>
</div>
<DIV style="position: absolute; top:50px; right:10px; width:70px; height:25px">
<form action="https://www.somesite.com/cgi-bin/something" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="image" src="https://www.somesite.com/somebut.gif" border="0" name="submit">
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----LONG_KEY...>
</form>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the form a name and use JavaScript to submit the form. You should also stay away from `<font>` and `<b>` tags; they're deprecated.

```
<!-- ... snip ... -->
<strong style="cursor: pointer; color: #FFF; " onclick="document.forms['someform'].submit(); ">Some Text Here</strong>
<!-- ... snip ... -->
<form name="someform" action="https://www.somesite.com/cgi-bin/something" method="post">
<!-- ... snip ... -->
```

If you prefer to use anchor tags to get all of the CSS pseudo-classes, etc., then you can do this instead of the bare `<strong>` tag:

```
<a href="#" style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; color: #FFF; " onclick="document.forms['someform'].submit(); return false; ">Some Text Here</a>
```

---

Finally, if you don't want to use JavaScript, then you'll have to do some rearranging of your markup and add some CSS, like so:

```
<form action="https://www.somesite.com/cgi-bin/something" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Some Text Here" style="background: none; border: 0; font-weight: bold; color: #FFF; " />
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
    <input type="image" src="https://www.somesite.com/somebut.gif" border="0" name="submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----LONG_KEY..." />
</form>
```

Add `<div>` tags as desired.

Comment: The `font` and `b` tags aren't deprecated, they just aren't standards.

Comment: The W3C would disagree with you: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#edef-FONT

Comment: Also... it turns out the `<b>` and `<i>` tags aren't deprecated. I always thought they were. No matter, `<b>` and `<i>` solely exist for visual effect, whereas `<strong>` and `<em>` have semantic value. If you're going for bold text without the semantics of the `<strong>` tag attached to the text, use CSS.

Comment: Now I know why I thought `<b>` and `<i>` were deprecated. `<u>` is deprecated, and the three typically go hand-in-hand. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#edef-U

Comment: Ah. And `<b>` and `<i>` were removed from XHTML2. http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/elements.html#a_elements I feel better now. :-)

Comment: I'd also be interested in a non java script solution.

Comment: Rilien, see my comment on erynion's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434486/how-do-i-add-descriptive-text-to-form-link-gif/2434733#2434733

Answer (score -1):

just wrap the "some text here with a link to the site"

```
<a href="https://www.somesite.com/cgi-bin/something"><font color="white"><b>Some Text Here<b></font></a>
```

Comment: I added a line to the code in my question - the encrypted key.  Just calling the cgi in you suggestion won't pass the key.

Comment: You realize that both `font` and `b` tags are not standard.